# Why isn't Django rendering my template?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a Django application and I'm just trying to push data up to the front-end to display.

In my `views.py` here's what I have:

```
def index(request):
    ...
    context = RequestContext(request)

    rooms = dict(db.studybug.find_one())

    timeRange = [room.encode('utf-8') for room in rooms['timeRange']]

    return render_to_response('studybug/index.html', timeRange, context)
```

Here, timeRange is a list that contains the following:

```
timeRange = ['Room 203A 10:00 AM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 10:30 AM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 11:00 AM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 11:30 AM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 12:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 12:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 3:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 3:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 4:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 4:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 5:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 5:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 6:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 6:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 7:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 7:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 8:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 8:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 9:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 9:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 10:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 10:30 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 11:00 PM \xc2\xa0', 'Room 203A 11:30 PM \xc2\xa0']
```

And then in my template (`index.html`), I have the following loop:

```
<div class="row">
    ...
  <ul>
    {% for item in timeRange %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

</div>
```

However, despite the list being generated in the backend, nothing is being displayed on the webpage. I know the list exists, but Django's rendering engine won't display it.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render_to_response` second parameter, should be a `dict` containing your data, you are passing a `list`.

your `render_to_response` should looks like this:

```
 return render_to_response('studybug/index.html', {'timeRange':timeRange}, context)
```

Comment: `'timeRage'` is nice, but you might want to change it to `'timeRange'`.

Answer (score 1):

while rendering you should give the `timerange` as key-value pair(ie dictionary format)

```
def my_view(request):
    timeRange = ['time1', 'time2', 'time3']  
    context = {'variable': 'value'}
    return render_to_response('studybug/index.html', {'timeRange': timeRange}, context)
```